# Is Modulus more efficient than And operator for finding halfs

Tags: operators, bit-manipulation, modulus, and-operator

I started playing with bitwise operators today I noticed that the `&` operator could be used to find if something is even or not.

```
100 & 1;//Gives 0
101 & 1;//Gives 1
```

Zeros for even and ones for odds.

So, I am currently wondering which is a more efficient method of finding if something is even:

A)`if (n & 1 == 0) isEven = true;`

or

B)`if(n % 2 == 0) isEven = true;`

Also, is there a more efficient way to find if something is even?

P.S. There is no reason that I need for an efficient way of finding if something is an even number, I am just genuinely curious.

Comment: Moved the comment to an answer since it was probably more suitable there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilers are pretty smart; if either is actually faster in practice, both `&1` and `%2` will quite possibly compile to the same - faster - code.

With a stupid compiler, I'd place a bet on `&1` being *at least as fast* as the alternative since it maps to bit operations which is a *very* basic operation for pretty much any CPU.

Modulo *may* be as fast on some CPUs, but definitely not so on low cost embedded CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

More efficient way:

```
isEven = !(n & 1);
```

Regarding using modulto operation %2 or so on:

On some compilers, it can generate longest/slowest code for signed integers,
because of, for example:

```
-5 % 2 == -1
```

For unsigned "n", usually compiler generate same code for both operations:

```
n % 2
n & 1
```